# Cant get code to execute in thread with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Here is the code it is supposed to scan and enumerate a directory and make hashes of whatever files it finds and append them to a dict the code all works separately but I cant get the hashing part to trigger within the threaded code there is no error

```
 import threading
 import tkinter as tk
 import tkinter.ttk as ttk
 import hashlib
 import glob


 class global_variables:
     def __init__(self):
         pass
     DirSelected = '' 
     Manifest = []

 class App(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.title("Progress bar example")
         self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_action)
         self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

     def start_action(self):
         self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

         t = threading.Thread(target=self.contar)
         t.start()

         self.windows_bar = WinProgressBar(self)

     def contar(self):

         directories_scanned = [str, 'File,Md5!']  # , separator value ! delineator adds new line
         target_dir = '/Users/kyle/PycharmProjects/' # this wont run 
         files = glob.glob(target_dir + '/**/*.*', recursive=True)  # Line adds search criteria aka find all all to the
         # directory for GLOB
         for file in files:
             with open(file, "rb") as f:
                 file_hash = hashlib.md5()
                 while chunk := f.read(8192):
                     file_hash.update(chunk)
                 directories_scanned.append(
                     file + ',' + str(file_hash.hexdigest() + '!'))  # Appends the file path and Md5
          global_variables.Manifest = directories_scanned

          for x in range(len(global_variables.DirSelected)):  # testing to view files TODO REMOVE this
             print(global_variables.DirSelected[x])
    
         for i in range(10): #to here 
             print("Is continuing", i)

         print('stop')

         self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
         self.windows_bar.destroy()
         self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)


 class WinProgressBar(tk.Toplevel):
     def __init__(self, parent):
         super().__init__(parent)
         self.title("Progress")
         self.geometry("300x200")
         self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, mode="indeterminate")
         self.progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
         self.progressbar.start(20)


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     global_variables()
     app = App()
     app.mainloop()
     print("Code after loop")
     for x in range(len(global_variables.DirSelected)):  # testing to view files TODO REMOVE this
          print(global_variables.DirSelected[x])
```

No errors can be shown this time the code will run

Comment: which part of the code exactly are you having problems with? I feel like this has nothing to do with `tkinter` and much more to do with `glob`, either how you should provide a [mre]

Comment: Outside of the tkinter class the glob code works as it’s supposed to when I put them together the glob code won’t run

Comment: so if you remove the last 3 lines from `contar`, then put that method outside of the class and run in another thread it will work but as soon as it is in that class it doesn't work? do you understand how little sense that makes? also if you call `tkinter` methods from threads (as in this case with the last 3 lines), `tkinter` can unexpectedly quit without any errors (also kinda your situation), but you are saying that `glob` doesn't work which makes no sense, did you try some simple debugging like `print(files)`? after the `glob.glob`?

Comment: I know, I’ve been having the devil working on it al day They both apart are working snippets of code when I stick em together they don’t play well

Comment: btw it seems like your path may be wrong, do you really run this file from a directory that contains a directory `Users`? and should it really be `'/**/*.*'` instead of `'/*/*.*'`?

Comment: @Matiiss no in production it won’t be run there I’m just running it here to develop it locally

Comment: but do you currently run the code there? it seems like an issue with path and how `glob.glob` thereby operates, nothing to do with `tkinter` because I just run this and it could search the directory so you will need to maybe "experiment" a bit with the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me. I think you just were checking the wrong variable `DirSelected` which was in fact an empty string. (see my code)

Also, I moved your `WinProgressBar` so it is available when the thread is executing. (was getting an exception on this).

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import hashlib
import glob


class global_variables:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    DirSelected = '' 
    Manifest = []

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Progress bar example")
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_action)
        self.button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    def start_action(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.windows_bar = WinProgressBar(self)

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.contar)
        t.start()

    def contar(self):

        directories_scanned = [str, 'File,Md5!']  # , separator value ! delineator adds new line
        target_dir = '/home/jsantos/workspace/blog.santos.cloud/' # this wont run 
        files = glob.glob(target_dir + '/**/*.*', recursive=True)  # Line adds search criteria aka find all all to the
        # directory for GLOB
        for file in files:
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                file_hash = hashlib.md5()
                while chunk := f.read(8192):
                    file_hash.update(chunk)
                directories_scanned.append(
                    file + ',' + str(file_hash.hexdigest() + '!'))  # Appends the file path and Md5
        global_variables.Manifest = directories_scanned

        for x in range(len(global_variables.Manifest)):  # testing to view files TODO REMOVE this
            print(global_variables.Manifest[x])
   
        for i in range(10): #to here 
            print("Is continuing", i)

        print('stop')

        self.windows_bar.progressbar.stop()
        self.windows_bar.destroy()
        self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

class WinProgressBar(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.title("Progress")
        self.geometry("300x200")
        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, mode="indeterminate")
        self.progressbar.place(x=30, y=60, width=200)
        self.progressbar.start(20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    global_variables()
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
    print("Code after loop")
    for x in range(len(global_variables.Manifest)):  # testing to view files TODO REMOVE this
        print(global_variables.Manifest[x])
```